# Android Studio 3.1 is not compiling/building the app, runs instantly

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I updated to Android Studio 3.1 along with other library updates like support-repository, HAXM, LLDB etc.

After update, when I tap run button(green-triangle),  the Android Studio instantly runs app without building. Any changes I made are not affected in the installed app. As soon as I tap run, It says:

```
> Installing app
> Launching activity
```

This happens in under 2 seconds. What could be wrong?

If I rebuild project, and then run the app. Same happens, but my changes appear in app.

When Android Studio was updating,  I chose to import settings from Android Studio 3.0 as well.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: May be this problem with your Instant run functionality please disable instabt run from setting

Comment: Disble Instant run. File->settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Instant Run disable checkbox.

Comment: Instant Run has been disabled from ages, I checked again. It hasn't moved.

Comment: I should have searched "Unexpected Behaviour" C:

Comment: Edit the Run Configuration and make sure the "Gradle-aware make" step is present before "Instant App Provision" step